# Issue with TileStream Tile URL

Tags: tiles, mapbox, mbtiles

First of all I'm new to Tilestream, MBTiles and GIS. 
As a part of of learning purpose I set up Tilestream with the help of tilestream tutorial and copied two MBTiles file to the tiles folder I am able to navigate to the tiles with the help of default Tilestream. 
http://localhost:8888 
But when loading the tile url it says 
Error: Tile does not exist
    at Statement. (/home/../tilestream/node_modules/mbtiles/lib/mbtiles.js:168:33)
can any one help me